# Access violation error while appending time to string in c++

Tags: c++, string, initialization, append

Take the following code:

```
#inlcude <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    time_t t;
    time(&t);

    string s = "file" + t;
    return 0;
}
```

At the line

```
string s = "file" + t
```

I get an access violation error.

If I change it to something like:
 #inlcude 
    using namespace std;

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    time_t t;
    time(&t);
    int x = t;

    string s = "file" + x;
    return 0;
}
```

I still get the same error.
What is up? Surely appending an int to a string can't throw an access violation?

Answer (score 5):

```
"file" + t
```

That does not do at all what you expect.  `"file"` is a char array.  You can't add an integer to a char array.  But you can add an integer to a pointer, and arrays are implicitly convertible to pointers.  The value of `t` is probably somewhere in the billions.  So the result of `"file" + t` is some pointer a billion or so bytes away from the char array `"file"`.  You then try to initialize a string with that pointer.  It's very unlikely that you have legal access to this memory location, so you get an access violation.  It's undefined behavior either way.  If you would have done this:

```
std::string s("file");
s += t;
```

You would have gotten a proper compiler error.  Try this instead:

```
std::string s("file");
s += std::to_string((long long)t);
```

If that function is not available to you (it's new in C++11), then you can use stringstreams:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "file" << t;
std::string s(oss.str());
```

Comment: You could also mention `boost::lexical_cast` if `to_string` isn't available.

Answer (score 2):

That is not the standard way to append an integer to a string. C++ represents a string as a pointer to a character array. By adding an integer to this, you are effectively incrementing the pointer to a block of memory that might not belong to you. Investigate the use of sprintf() for what you need.

Comment: As a follow-up to this, check out this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf. You can also use C++ String Streams to achieve what you want: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream

Comment: Sort of kind of correct. C++ represents a string with `std::string`, *and the OP is using that in his code*. You're right that C++ represents *string literals* as pointers to char arrays (or simply as char arrays in some cases). But your explanation is going to be very misleading to someone who doesn't already know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your strings aren't strings.

You need to remember that string literals (of the form `"foo"` are not of type `std::string`, but `const char*` (actually they have type `const char[N]`, but for our purposes, we can consider them to be pointers).

So when you write code such as this:

```
std::string foo = "bar" + 42
```

then the types involved as as follows:

```
std::string = const char* + int
```

In other words, your code is adding an integer to a pointer, and then the *resulting* char pointer is stored as a string.

Note that adding an integer to a pointer is just plain pointer arithmetics, so the compiler won't complain.

If we do this instead:

```
std::string foo = std::string("bar") + 42
```

then we create a proper string, and then try to add 42 to that. That's not defined, so we'll get a compiler error (which is at least better than silently doing the wrong thing).

The correct solution is to use a stream, as shown in one of the other answers:

```
std::ostringstream os("file");
os << x;
std::string s = os.str();
```